# Changing to PTP MTP from charging mode?

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, mtp

So now, I just plugged my phone which is a Samsung Galaxy J2 Prime (SM-G532G), a notification pops up if I want an MTP or PTP devices, since I am charing I chose Charging on USB mode. Now when I plugged my phone that notification is nowhere in sight so I cannot change back to PTP or MTP.

[EDIT]
Just like to point out one thing. I've been using this same exact cable for software development purporses so yes it is working when I use MTP and for data transfer. I just don't have the option anymore to switch from USB Charging mode to either MTP to PTP.

Any ideas?

Phone:
- Samsung Galaxy J2 Prime (SM-G532G)
- Android 6.0.1

Thanks!

Comment: Enable developer options (by tapping build number 7 times ) and from the USB related options change the default. Samsung often changes options and calls it by some other name so you may have to search

Comment: @beeshyams is there an option to change the Charging mode to PTP or MTP? Jesus christ where is that notification item!???!!!!?? This is frustrating. I need to change it back to MTP so I can debug. I restarted the phone and everytime I plug the phone to PC it kept on charging.

Comment: See if this helps http://thecellguide.com/usb-connection-not-working-on-a-samsung-galaxy-smartphone/

Comment: With the device in charging mode and the cable connected, go to *Settings › Storage* – AFAIR there's an option to enable sharing behiund the triple-dot menu.

Comment: There is none unfortunately, what I did is I simply unplug my phone, restart my phone and I turned off and turned on my Dev option and made sure the default USB connection option is set to MTP/PTP and then I restarted my phone again. 

It seems to be fixed now but at the cost of such a massive frustration that such a simple option should be listed on settings menu

Answer (score 2):

First go this path:
    About Device --> Software Info --> Click to Build Number up to enable Developet option in mobile.

Then go to Setting and open this path:
    Developer Option --> USB Configuration --> Change mode from Charging to MTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach this setting in another way by dialing *#0808#, it will take you straight to the USB Settings. Tap on AP then MTP. You may need to reboot.